# Getting confused with AND and OR when using NULL

Tags: sql-server

I'm not a trained SQL person, but I can usually write basic queries.  But this has got me confused.

A subset of the table is:

```
fldUID (auto-increment unique)
fldSrcAddress
fldDstAddress
fldSrcDNSHost
fldDstDNSHost
```

I'm trying to retrieve the fldUID of records that DO have a fldSrcAddress or fldDstAddress,  AND either fldSrcDNSHost is NULL or fldDstDNSHost is NULL.

My Query is:

```
SELECT top 1 fldUID, fldSrcAddress, fldDstAddress
From tbl_ExtLog_FirewallTraffic
Where fldSrcAddress Is Not Null or fldDstAddress is not null
And (fldSrcDNSHost Is Null Or fldDstDNSHost is null )
order by fldUpdateTimeStamp asc
```

But the query returns fldUID 32831, which is:

```
Example Data: 
fldUID = 32831
fldSrcAddress = 192.168.1.100
fldDstAddress = 192.168.2.69
fldSrcDNSHost = Asus
fldDstDNSHost = Lucifer
```

Fields 2 and 3 both have data (so that makes sense).  But fields 4 and 5 also have data, but my query is trying to find records where either field 4 or 5 is NULL.

Obviously a stupid mistake - any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be issue of brackets.

Try this :

```
SELECT top 1 fldUID, fldSrcAddress, fldDstAddress
From tbl_ExtLog_FirewallTraffic
Where (fldSrcAddress Is Not Null OR fldDstAddress is not null)
And (fldSrcDNSHost Is Null Or fldDstDNSHost is null )
order by fldUpdateTimeStamp asc
```

Comment: That works - Now I feel silly.  I tried putting an extra bracket before the AND and at the end of the line, but I didn't think to put them around the first two conditions.  It makes sense now I look at it!  Thank you.

Comment: A third set of eye sometimes do help :) Now try to identify why without brackets you were getting that record.

Comment: :-)  Without brackets, it doesn't process past the first statement (fldSrcAddress Is Not Null) - it returns the first row where fldSrcAddress is not null.  ?     Thanks for asking the question - it helps me to understand what I was doing wrong :-)